# Rewriting sorting algorithm. Bad code or just bad spacing

Tags: sorting, haskell

I'm trying to teach myself Haskell, so I've been trying to rewrite pieces of code in another way. I found this sorting algorithm on an online tutorial and was trying to see if there were better ways to write this.

Here's what I wrote

```
  quickerSort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
  quickerSort [] = []
  quickerSort (x:xs) = smallList ++ [x] ++ bigList
                     where let smallList = quickerSort [a | a<-xs, a <= x]
                               bigList = quickerSort [a | a<-xs, a > x]
```

And here's what I was trying to rewrite in my own way.

```
quicksort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]  
quicksort [] = []  
quicksort (x:xs) =   
    let smallerSorted = quicksort [a | a <- xs, a <= x]  
        biggerSorted = quicksort [a | a <- xs, a > x]  
    in  smallerSorted ++ [x] ++ biggerSorted
```

The interpreter yeilds "parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)," but I tried different spacing and it did not work. I was just wondering if I just wrote the function incorrectly.

If it is indeed a spacing error, then can somebody link a tutorial that teaches correct haskell spacing?

Thanks!

Comment: Remove the `let`. Also, your `quickerSort` is wrong since it does not recursively sorts the sublists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`where let` is invalid syntax; just write `where` there.

Comment: `where` is an alternative to `let` where things are just in the opposite order.  You write either `let var = foo in code` or `code where var = foo` (though there are some constructs where `let` can be used but not `where`).

Comment: Is one faster than another? Or do they function the same?

Comment: @Maz: Any differences between them are erased during compilation.  They're exactly the same speed.

Comment: GHC's intermediate core language has only `let`, not `where`, so they more or less have to be desugared to the same thing.